# Update UITableViewCell on UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently implementing swiping functionality for my custom table view cell and I came across the problem. I want my `UIScrollView` embedded in cell to reset its `contentOffset` on table view scroll. The only possible solution I came up with at the moment is to retrieve `visibleCells` from table view on each `scrollViewDidScroll` call, cast it to my type and then apply modifications to each of them but I think it might be quite costly and will probably affect performance on older devices. Is there any better way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use NotificationCenter.

1. Post a notification to NotificationCenter within ´scrollViewDidScroll´
2. within your cell’s subclass, use ´NotificationCenter.default.addObderver() and reset the contentOffset whenever this notification has been received.